# Toad Movement Model Example

Tags: probability

This is a repost of a [question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/639693/toad-movement-model-example/639699?noredirect=1#comment1195861_639699) from a different forum that didn't get much attention and I am dying for a further explanation/elaboration.

Before I proceed, this is against community standards, please comment below and I will take it down.

---

This model of toad movement is presented in an [article](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S030438001630850X). I'm confused at to how the probabilities are set out and was wondering why if $P(\text{return}) = \sum_i p_{ret(i)}$ then why is

$$ 1 - p_{ret} = \prod (1-p_{ret(i)}) \neq 1 - \sum_i p_{ret(i)}, $$

since the events of returning to each specific site are mutually exclusive.

> Model 3 (distance-based return probability):<sup>[src)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4hJm3.png)</sup> probability of returning to a given site decays exponentially with the distance $d_i$ to that refuge:
> $$ p_{ret(i)} = p_0 e^{-d_i/d_0}, \tag{1} $$
> where $d_0$ is a characteristic distance to be estimated along with $p_0$. The probability of not returning to any previous site is the product of the complements of the $p_{ret(i)}$:
> $$ 1 - p_{ret} = \prod_{i=1}^{R} (1-p_{ret(i)}), \tag{2} $$
> where $R$ is the number of distinct previous refuges. In the case of a return event, the probability of each refuge being chosen is given by:
> $$ P(\text{return at $i$} | \text{return}) = \frac{p_{ret(i)}}{\sum p_{ret(i)}} \tag{3} $$

Comment: You would want to make your question self-contained, instead of redirecting users to a paid article...

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, the article doesn't adequately define the variables and underlying assumptions, although I imagine part of this is because they assume the reader can fill in the gaps.

I'm not a biologist or ecologist, so I don't have that specific domain knowledge.  But my understanding is that we have a number of distinct sites $1, 2, \ldots, R$, and the frog can return to one of these sites with some probability.  In the first model, they use the notation $p_{\text{ret}}$ to characterize the probability of returning to any random refuge.  In the second model, $p_{\text{ret}}$ describes the probability of return to the (spatially) nearest refuge.

In the third model, the distance of each site is taken into account, so the authors extend the notation to accommodate different probabilities of return for each site:

$$p_{\text{ret}(i)} = p_0 e^{-d_i/d_0},$$

where $p_0$ is a kind of probability scaling factor that applies to all sites, $d_i$ is the distance to site $i$, and $d_0$ is distance scaling factor.  So the parameters to be estimated in this model are $p_0$ and $d_0$.  What this gives us is a series of probabilities of return for each distinct site, $p_{\text{ret}(1)}, p_{\text{ret}(2)}, \ldots, p_{\text{ret}(R)}$.  Note that these do *not* need to add to $1$.  The frog does not have to return to any previous site.

So we know that in order for the frog to not return to any of these previous refuges, each refuge must be refused, so this probability is $$\prod_{i=1}^R (1 - p_{\text{ret}(i)}).$$
Also note that at no point do the authors claim
$$p_{\text{ret}} = \sum_{i=1}^R p_{\text{ret}(i)}.$$
This equation does not appear anywhere in the text.  The model does not assume that the frog only ever returns to one site.  If that were the case, then the estimation of $d_0$ and $p_0$ would need to obey additional constraints not stated, which is not the case.  This is why the correct probability of not returning to any site is given by the product of each of the individual site non-return probabilities, rather than the complement of the sum of individual return probabilities.